# Почему прописывается лишний стиль?

Tags: jquery, php, mysql

В таблице хранится текст `<p>ТЕКСТ</p>`. Вывожу его в аккардеон :

```
echo ("<p>{$rezult['anot']}<br><br> .......</p>");
```

Но он у меня прописывается при выходе

```
<p style="display: none; ">чмчм</p>
```

Т.е. прописка есть, но какого лешего и откуда прописывается стиль (`style="display: none;`) Т.е. не показывать? Ведь в стилях у меня ничего такого нет и не было.
Привожу кусок стилей с тегом p

```
.accordion p {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    margin: 0;
    padding:  100px 15px 20px;
    border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    border-right: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего уже после загрузки его дописывает скрипт аккордеона

Comment: но это невозможно. ОН же может сам по себе писать что ему вздумается?

Comment: Есть где посмотреть? 

Если вы смотрели из фаерфокса ("исходный код выделенного фрагмента"), то он покажет то же самое, если стиль установился javascript'ом.

Comment: 100% ТС смотрит в дебагере<br>(не один фаербаг такое может ;))

Comment: пишите адекватные названия темы

Comment: Все смотрел. Проблема в теге П. Он двойной получается ПП но и убрать его нельзя. Что же делать? Можно уже при выводе вырезать этот тег из переменной?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что если хотите вывести даный стиль, нужно прописывать так:

```
<p class="accordion">{$rezult['anot']}<br><br> .......</p>
```

или запихнуть в div с класом акордеон стиль p. Тянет не то? Потому что вы указали просто стили к p.

Или возможен вариант просто переназначить стили к p

```
p {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    margin: 0;
    padding:  100px 15px 20px;
    border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    border-right: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал оба способа - не помогло (((((((